# Firedac SQLite returning wrong values

Tags: sqlite, delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

My SQLite database contains table `players`. In DB Browser the data in the table is correct, however when retrieving the data it is returning a different value.

Value in database: `76561198113034550`, value returned: `152768822`. I'm getting the value by:

```pascal
qryPlayers.Close;
qryPlayers.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM players';
qryPlayers.Open;

playerID := qryPlayers.FieldByName('steamid').Value; // .AsString returns the same value
```

Whats causing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: It's difficult to see what might be causing that from what you've posted. Does the value 152768822 appear anywhere in the dB?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just checked, what value the 4 lower bytes of `76561198113034550` have... And tadaaa, it is `152768822`! So the upper 4 bytes are simply truncated.

Declare `playerID` as `Int64`, not `Integer` or `Cardinal` since those types only have 4 bytes in memory.
And for retrieving the value from the DB use `qryPlayers.FieldByName('steamid').AsLargeInt`.